# why does calling free() after heap overflow result in crash - what is the exact reason?

Tags: c, memory, free, glibc

I wrote a simple program for heap overflow (providing larger input than the memory allocated), and when I try to print that input, I am getting the complete string (because retrieving is done till we encounter '\0' in memory), it is clear till this part.

But when I called `free()`, system crashed and got some error message like this

```
free() invalid next size (fast) aborted (core dumped): some_address
```

here the address points to the base address of memory allocated via `malloc`.

Below is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    scanf("%s", string);     //intentionally i am providing input much longer than 10 bytes
    printf("\n string input given by user is %s\n", string);
    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```

on my way towards knowing the exact reason for this crash, I got to know what metadata does both live and free chunks contain, and little bit about "bins" managed by GLIBC.

I got to know, metadata that a live chunk store is: size(specifies how much I have requested for, and it will be aligned to either 8 or 16), and few bits which speaks about arena, previous chunk, off-heap, and in the end there will be pointer to previous chunk (if previous chunk is free).

Initially I thought the previous chunk might be empty and when GLIBC tried to fetch previous chunk address and merge with the chunk which I am passing it to free(), it encountered some junk values in previous chunk pointer field because of the overflow I did, but later when I saw `free()` function definition and the error message, more clearly, I got to know it has something to do with *fastbins*, and fast bins don't merge chunks with previous chunks, so my assumption is wrong.

Can anyone of you explain the exact reason for the crash?
I tried reading code, and got lost as some point of time when they are doing "chunk_at_offset"

Explaining from code and some pictorial representation would be very much helpful

[This](https://github.com/sploitfun/lsploits/blob/master/glibc/malloc/malloc.c#L3859%20and%20https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=6e766d11bc85b6480fa5c9f2a76559f8acf9deb5;hb=HEAD#l4239) is the link to the source code I am referring.

edit:
I am using onlinegdb c compiler for this, I tried the same in my personal machine where I had Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1, and my system is pretty much stable even for huge input

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), where anything could really happen (including [summoning nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)).

Comment: To get an answer, you need to be more specific, compiler, architecture etc. There is no globally defined undefined behaviour.

Comment: Take this as an unofficial answer, since I don't know if it applies to your specific implementation. I've seen heaps implemented as _"linked lists"_ of memory management structures: an header, the actual data section, and a footer with some magic numbers (contained in the header too). You can imagine how the free consists in removing the element X from the list, linking the element X+1 to the element X-1. But if you write after the allocated size you corrupted all the magic numbers, making the next element invalid and impossible to be linked back to the previous element. ==> Crash.

Comment: well I feel this undefined behaviour is just "un-defined behaviour", which means we haven't put efforts to analyse how the system behaves. I am telling this with very less industry experience, once I gain some experience I also might agree and satisfy when someone say "undefined behaviour". and by the way it is just a machine, I don't know if it can work in an undefined way, there has to be something defined so that the system knows when, what to do and how to do.

Comment: Why care about the exact reason?  You wrote out-of-bounds, blew away the C sub-allocator  metadata and so free() crashed.  Why do you need more?  Stop doing bad things:)

Comment: @EllantiKishore `I don't know if it can work in an undefined way` It *is* a well defined crash in each individual run, which you can debug in full detail, of course. But it may *not* necessarily be the *same* crash between runs, and it most likely is not the same crash between the same code compiled with different compilers, or for different bitnesses, or for different platforms, or even for different versions of the same platform. So you could think of "undefined behavior" as standing for "many different behaviors which we cannot all guess in advance, and don't care to even try most of time".

Comment: can you mention reason for down voting? so that I can try to correct in my feature posts

Comment: For what it's worth I'm not the downvoter, and I would place a bet on the assumption I described in the comment above (even if I admit I had no time to browse the code you linked).

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone of you explain the exact reason for the crash?

The *exact* reason for the crash is the the heap implementation inside GLIBC was able to detect heap corruption *in this particular case*, and called `abort()`.

As others have said, you are exercising undefined behavior, so *anything* can happen.

On a different system, or with a different version of GLIBC, or for a different user, or when setting different environment variables, this crash may no longer happen (and that is *not a bug*).

> I feel this undefined behaviour is just "un-defined behaviour", which means we haven't put efforts to analyse how the system behaves.

It is *pointless* to analyze the system behavior: you are playing russian roulette. You may get lucky and in your particular environment the gun is either completely empty or completely full, so you get predictable behavior. But you can't make *any* conclusions from this -- on a different system, or tomorrow, the system may behave differently.